# Issue SELECT with temporary table

Tags: sql-server

I am able to DROP and CREATE a temporary table but when I do a select, it doesn't recognize the object. I know it's there but how can I access it?
FYI, I have multiple databases in SQL Server (2008). I tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM tempdb..#TBL_IMPORT
```

Usually to access tables I have to type this: dbname.dbo.tablename
Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to access it from the same session that you created it with?  Current connection `#table` vs Global `##table`.

Comment: Don't qualify it with the `tempdb`. Just `SELECT * FROM #TBL_IMPORT;`

Comment: Temp Tables have a scope of the current connection/session. So you have to reference it from where you create it. You can't create it in one window and then access it in another window or at a different time or from a different session or collection. And you just reference it with #TBL_IMPORT ... the only time you qualify it with tempdb. is when you're testing for existence before dropping it, for example.

Comment: Thank you pmbAustin. That was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the amount of information given, the answer is in the comments.

If you would like to query a temp table from a second session, you'll need to create the temp table as a global temp table.

```
select *
  into ##MyGlobalTable
  from SourceTable
```

If you're using SSMS you will want to use the same window you create the temp table in if not using a global temp table. If you're using a secondary application you'll want to validate you're using the same SPID.

Other approaches you may be interested in would include CTEs (common table expressions) and variable tables. Google will have a wide assortment of assistance, or you could update your question here.

Comment: The global table works as well. Thank you Random_User